# How is Fiscal horsepower calculated in Spain?

Tags: taxes, car, spain

The annual circulation tax (Impuesto sobre vehículos de tracción mecánica) is imposed in Spain on an annual basis based on a Fiscal horsepower.  Does anybody know the formula for calculating fiscal horsepower from physical properties of the vehicle?

I am looking for the formula, or algorithm, as opposed to a specific case.

Comment: This is related to personal finance, how ?? And it pays to be courteous when you want others to help.

Comment: @DumbCoder Assuming the Spanish system is similar to the one I'm used to, fiscal HP will determine the tax costs involved in purchasing/leasing the vehicle so will affect OP's budget. But I'm not sure why you're taking issue with the tone of the post: it seems entirely matter-of-fact.

Comment: @Grimley - Welcome to Money.SE. Your question proves that there's always something new to learn, if not in our own countries, about how these things are handled elsewhere. I hope someone familiar with this issue will post soon, and help you out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [ACEA 2016 Tax Guide](http://www.acea.be/uploads/news_documents/ACEA_TAX_GUIDE_2016.pdf), page 250:

> a). for four-stroke internal combustion or spark ignition engines:
>
> > hp = 0.080 * (0.785 * D^2 * R)^0.6 * N
>
> b). for two-stroke internal combustion or spark ignition engines:
>
> > hp = 0.11 * (0.785 * D^2 * R)^0.6 * N
>
> Where:
>
> > D = the diameter of the cylinder in cm
> >
> > R = the stroke of the piston in cm
> >
> > N = the number of cylinders of the engine
>
> c). for rotary engines
>
> > hp = Re/7
>
> Where:
>
> > Re= effective rating

Comment: that Acea Tax guide looks awesome - I'd been using two other similar books written for fleet managers, and they just didn't go into the detail I need.  Thanks @Joe - you have just answered my next 100 questions.